# Schrödinger equation in spherical coordinates using Numerov's method?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, computational-physics

So I need to solve the Schrödinger equation using [Numerov's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerov's_method). However, the problem I have assigned to me is in spherical coordinates. As it seems, I only need to take into account the dependance with the radius. When I develop the term for the kinetic energy, a first derivative appears, which I can't seem to fit into Numerov's algorithm, since, as far as I know, it's used for specifically for expressions without a first derivative.

My question is: can I apply Numerov to solve the equation in spherical coordinates? If so, what modifications to the "normal" algorithm are necessary?

In case it helps, the potential is that of a deuteron, with the form $V(r)=-A e^{-r/a}$

I also thought of maybe using Runge-Kutta, in case Numerov is not a viable option.

PS: If anyone has a link to a good guide about numerically solving the equation, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Would [scicomp.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: To solve the eigenvalue problem as an ordinary differential equation (to be able to use Numerov's method), see also
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_method

Comment: one of my students has used  Numerov method  while dealing with three body  bound state  problems and i will look for and post the references/links  shortly.