# Putting the Schrödinger equation in dimensionless form

Tags: homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, dimensional-analysis

The Schrödinger equation in spherical coordinates after separation of variables, for the hydrogen atom, is given by

$$
\frac{-\hbar^{2}}{2m} \biggl[ \frac{1}{r^{2}} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \biggl(r^{2} \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial r} \biggr)-\frac{l (l + 1)}{r^{2}} \psi \biggr] + V(r)\psi = E \psi
$$

The boundary conditions required by quantum mechanics are $\psi \to 0$ as $r \to \infty$, and $\psi$ remains finite as $r \to 0$. To implement this latter change the variable to $u = r \psi$; $u$ then
satisfies
$$
\frac{-\hbar^{2}}{2m} \biggl[ u'' - \frac{l (l + 1)}{r^{2}} u \biggr] + V(r) u = E u
$$

As $r \to 0$, $u = r \psi \to 0$ provided $\psi$ remains finite. The boundary condition is therefore $u = 0$ at $r = 0$.

Can anyone please help me in putting this equation in dimensionless form by introducing the $a$ length scale?

Comment: I would suggest you to use trapezoidal method (unless it is a necessity of your assignment) because it decreases the complexity of you code quite a bit and you will be in less danger of making coding errors.

Comment: What is $a$?  I think you need to substitute $r=\rho a$ where $\rho$ is the dimensionless radius.

Answer (score 1):

You can substitute:

$$u(r) = f(\lambda r)$$

in the differential equation and choose $\lambda$ so that the left hand side becomes dimensionless up to some overall factor (you can then absorb what's left into E and f). You can also reason as follows. You know that $\lambda= \frac{\hbar}{m c}$ has the dimensions of a length, it is the Compton wavelength of the electron. This means that

$$\frac{e^2}{\lambda}$$

in units where $\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0} = 1$ has the dimensions of energy. If we divide this by $m c^2$, the result will be the dimensionless number:

$$\alpha = \frac{e^2}{\lambda m c^2} = \frac{e^2}{\hbar c}$$

The length scale appropriate for the hydrogen atom is not the Compton wavelength as we're in the non-relativistic limit. That non-relativistic limit cannot contain factors of $c$. We can obtain this by multiplying the Compton wavelength by some power of $\alpha$ such that $c$ drops out. Clearly you have to divide by $\alpha$, the length scale is the so-called Bohr length:

$$a_0 = \frac{\hbar^2}{m e^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

There are few choice here. One length scale is the Bohr radius $a_0$. By using this scale, the corresponding frequency scale and energy  scale can be defined as $a_0 = \sqrt{\hbar/(2m \omega_0)}$ and $E_0 = \hbar \omega_0$ respectively. Substitute these back, you will get the dimensionless equation.

Suppose you are trying to find the ground state, you can use the imaginary time method together with the repeated normalization. Note that the normalization constant of the the $u$ is not 1 because of the substitution, it should be something like $\int dr |u|^2 = \frac{1}{4\pi}$ if I remember correctly. You need to derive it yourself from the original normalization.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/246771/562

Answer (score 0):

Writing the equation as $$u'' - \frac{l (l + 1)}{r^{2}} u = \frac{2m}{\hbar^2} \left( V(r)- E \right) u$$ both sides have the dimensions of $\frac{1}{L^2}$. To put in dimensionless form you need to multiply through by the square of a suitable length scale. This is problem dependent and the relevant scale length you need to use is for significant changes in the potential $V(r)$. For $V(r) = -\frac{e^2}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r}$, the Coulomb potential, look at the expression $\frac{2m}{\hbar^2} \frac{e^2}{4 \pi \epsilon_0}$ that multiplies the $\frac{1}{r}$ term. It must be that the expression $\frac{\hbar^2 4 \pi \epsilon_0}{me^2}$ has the units of length, so the appropriate scale factor in this case is $a_0 = \frac{4 \pi \epsilon_0 \hbar^2}{me^2}$ (which is the Bohr length). If your potential is a fixed range $a$ and depth $V_0$, *i.e.* $V(r) = \begin{cases} -V_0 & r<a, \\ \,\,\,\,\,\,0 & r>a. \end{cases}$ then it would natural to take the length scale as the range of the potential, $a$. Similarly, for the potential $V=- V_0 e^{-\lambda r}$ it would be natural to take the appropriate length scale as $1/\lambda$.